# Kotlin basic inheritance solution

Tags: java, oop, kotlin

How do I make new `SavingAccount` with init values for `owner` and `balance`

```
open class BankAccount(val owner: String = "Long John Silver", private var balance: Double = 0.00) {

    constructor (amount: Double) : this() {
        this.balance = amount
    }
    fun deposit(amount: Double){
        this.balance += amount
    }
    fun withdraw(amount: Double){
        this.balance -= amount
    }
    fun getBalance(): Double{
        return this.balance
    }
}
```

And the child class

```
class SavingAccount(val increasedBy: Double = 0.05): BankAccount(){

    fun addInterest(): Unit{
        val increasedBy = (this.getBalance() * increasedBy)
        deposit(amount = increasedBy)
    }
}
```

and in main

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val sa = SavingAccount();// how to do this SavingAccount("Captain Flint", 20.00)
    println(sa.owner)
    println(sa.owner)
}
```

How can I create `SavingAccount` for a new user, without default values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement it with ordinary Constructor-Arguments (hence no Properties) and pass them into your `BankAccount`

```
class SavingAccount(owner: String,
        balance: Double,
        val increasedBy: Double = 0.05
): BankAccount(owner, balance) {

}
```

Default values for `SavingAccount` can be defined similar to `BankAccount`:

```
class SavingAccount(owner: String = "Default Owner",
        balance: Double = 0.0,
        val increasedBy: Double = 0.05
): BankAccount(owner, balance) {

}
```

Comment: worked but the default values are kinda very strange, because i have to do in every child class. over and over...

Comment: Overriding functions where the overridden function has [default arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments) automatically get the defaults from the overridden function (in fact, it isn't even possible to specify other defaults). It looks like constructors don't work that way.

Comment: @Jesper Its different. Inside the Saving-Account constructor we are not really overriding the properties of Banking, thats why we must declare default values

Answer (score 2):

Change your class declaration to

```
class SavingAccount(owner: String, 
                    balance: Double, 
                    val increasedBy: Double = 0.05): BankAccount(owner, balance)
```